# Dotless adding extra '../' directory path

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, less, dotless

I have these variables:

```
@images-url: '../../../Images/';
@theme-images-url: '@{images-url}portal-themes/default/';
@theme-icons-url: '@{theme-images-url}icons/';
```

And this is how I use it:

```
background: url('@{theme-icons-url}buttonsheet.png') -2px no-repeat;
```

This works perfectly locally. However the images are missing on the server version. When I view the generated LESS file this is the resulting CSS:

```
background: url('../../../../Images/portal-themes/cgi/icons/buttonsheet.png') -2px no-repeat;
```

If I edit the server version to:

```
@images-url: '../../Images/';
```

Then the resulting CSS is:

```
background: url('../../../Images/portal-themes/cgi/icons/buttonsheet.png') -2px no-repeat;
```

This is obviously correct on the server but then broken on my local machine. I want to prevent this extra `../` been added so it works on both machines.

Why has an extra `../` been added to the start of my path on my server? I can't see any reason why this would happen.

Comment: Why are you using relative paths all together? - most likely the images folder is on root of the site, so `@images-url: '/Images/';` would be better

Comment: @Leon For technical reasons beyond my control. It's immaterial really, the question is why is dotless messing with my urls? Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use one less '../'?

Comment: @AdamMcquiff Then it's broken locally. So as explained above, no.

Comment: It is very strange, the variables don't change by themselves. And if you escape the paths like this?: `@images-url: ~'../../../Images/';` - _it's just a suggestion, I'm not sure it will work_

Comment: @blonfu Yeah that's what's puzzling me. I guess the next step is to go through the dotless code and debug it. Incidentally i tried that fix and it didn't work.

Comment: Known issue and apparently fixed https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/34